# Capybara: Back to back form submission

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I am using capybara for writing the testcases. My code flow is  as follows

1) User log in and is redirected to select gender page (gender is radio button).

2) On selecting gender and clicking "proceed", user should redirect to home page.

3) On not selecting any gender and clicking on "proceed" user should redirect to same page.

I am writing test case for this using capybara in rails.

My test case is as follows

```
before :each do
      @user = User.create(:login => "test", :password => "123456", :email => "test@email.com", :status => true)          
      visit '/users/sign_in'
      fill_in "user[email]", :with => @user.login
      fill_in "user[password]", :with => @user.password
      click_button "LOGIN"
      choose("gender")
      click_button "PROCEED"
    end

    after :each do
      visit "/logout"
    end

    it "signs me in to D360" do
      current_path.should eq('/')
    end
```

I added a puts statement in action where second form gets submitted, I found that it is getting printed twice. When i checked referer, the request seem to come from two different pages, one from login page and other from select gender page. I cannot understand why it is working like that. There should be something for back to back form submission in capybara which I am doing wrong, I can't understand.

Comment: Are you sure the user is actually being signed in? You filled in `user[email]` with the value of `user.login`.

Comment: yeah here user can sign in using email and login both. so it is actually not a problem.